# css nth-child selector on n floated elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I use css selector `nth-child(...)` on floated elements to achieve this result?

[image]

```
<ol>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li style="background: red;">Text</li>
</ol>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kcxdrozf/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `4n+1` for odd selections on LHS and `4n` for selections on RHS.

```
ol li:nth-child(4n+1),
ol li:nth-child(4n) {
    background: red;
}
```

```css
ol {
  width: 270px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
ol li:nth-child(4n+1),
ol li:nth-child(4n) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcxdrozf/1/)

Comment: Using `:not()` you can make a single rule: `ol li:not(4n+2):not(4n+3)` :D